# Try to detect sniffers in my lan using ARP

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, arp, sniffing

i try to detect sniffing in my LAN. when i send an arp packet to FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FE with the ip of the sniffing PC the pc doesn't recive the packet( thr packet doesn't apper in wireshark in the sniffing pc but apper in wireshark on the sending pc. How can i detect sniffing in my lan using ARP

```
import sys
i, o, e = sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr
from scapy.all import *
sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr = i, o, e

def main():

   #create an ARP packet for 192.168.1.25 the sniffing PC
   packet = Ether(dst = 'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FE')/ARP(pdst='192.168.1.25',hwdst = 
   'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FE')
   while True:
   #sending the packet until we get an answer
     pa = srp1(packet,timeout=1)
     if pa is not None:
     #if there is an answer print the packet and break
        print pa.show()
        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set `hwdst` in the arp packet!
Also [`scapy`](https://github.com/secdev/scapy) has a *built-in* method, [`promiscping(ip or CIDR block)`](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/l2.py#L524) that does exactly that.

Comment: this does not help me,I tried it but still there wasn't an answer fro, the sniffing pc who run wireshark

Comment: what do you mean interface?